# how to filter, then pipe and use sum function?

Tags: r, tidyverse

For Example the following will not work:

```
data(mpg)

filter(mpg, manufacturer =="audi") %>%
    sum(.$cty)
```

However the following will work:

```
data(mpg)

x <- filter(mpg, manufacturer =="audi")

sum(x$cty)
```

I would like to get it all to work in a piping flow if possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use `pull` to get column as a vector and then use `sum`.

```
library(dplyr)

mpg %>%
  filter(manufacturer =="audi") %>%
  pull(cty) %>%
  sum
#[1] 317
```

---

Your attempt does not work because pipes send output of LHS as first argument to the function in RHS. So a dataframe is being passed as first argument in `sum`. It will work if you use `{}` around it.

```
filter(mpg, manufacturer =="audi") %>% {sum(.$cty)}
```

Comment: what is LHS and RHS, and what do the {} do essentially in laymen terms?

Comment: @MilesMorales Left-hand-side, right-hand-side. If you do `mpg %>%  summarise(sum = sum(cty))` the first argument of `?summarise` is `.data` which is `mpg` and it is implicitly passed to `summarise` here using pipes. Using `{}` we can stop that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

We could do this without the `filter` step by doing this in `summarise` itself

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
mpg %>% 
   summarise(out = sum(cty[manufacturer == "audi"])) %>%
   pull(out)
 #[1] 317
```